# show external site with own domain

Tags: redirect, cross-domain

Is it possible to map part of my own domain to an external domain:

```
mydomain.com/blog/articles/2
```

Should open

```
blog.com/articles/2
```

The url shown to the user should still be:

```
mydomain.com/blog/articles/2
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "proxy". Yes, it's possible. It's not always a simple undertaking, and if `blog.com` isn't yours there are legal/copyright issues at play.

Comment: Also called a "reverse proxy" or if it is just a couple of individual pages, an iframe may already be sufficient